# Flex Remoting or Flash Remoting

Tags: apache-flex, flash, remoting

Can you suggest which Remoting service is good either flash or flex.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Do you mean Remote service for flash and flex.  Flash and flex is not a remote service.

Comment: Remoting Service for Flash & Flex, i want to know which is best.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need data services, you may consider:
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/livecycle_dataservices3/
or

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/

Otherwise, you may consider AMF protocol.  I cannot say it is the best, but I like this one.

For AMF, it will depends on which technology that you are using.

For php, if you need a framework to work with, you may consider
http://framework.zend.com/download/amf,
otherwise, a more simple solution is:
http://www.amfphp.org/.

For python, you can try:
http://pyamf.org/

In addition, you may have a look of The Midnight Coders' web sites:
http://www.themidnightcoders.com/

Wish this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are asking about the server technologies, since both Flex and Flash use the same client side remoting.

In regards to the server you have a lot of choices, but I'm a big fan of the Adobe's open source [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/), which is Java based.  Definately check that out, unless you really like to manually serialize your objects.  There is another Java based AMF server called [Granite Data Services](http://www.graniteds.org), but I have no experience with that.

If Java on the server isn't your cup of tea, I know there an AMF implementation in Ruby as well as Python ([RubyAMF](http://code.google.com/p/rubyamf/), [PyAMF](http://pyamf.org/)).  I'm sure the .NET guys have one as well.

And if you are curious about other ways to push server data across the wire (RESTful XML or traditional Web Services), take a look at James Ward's benchmarking site [here.](http://www.jamesward.com/census/)

Good luck.